# Generate one random index from an array but exclude one. javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate one random number from an array but exclude one index and return the index of the random number.
I tried this:

```
function randNum(arr,excludeNum){
    var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
    if(arr[randNumber]==excludeNum){
        randNum(arr,excludeNum);
    }else{
        return randNumber;
    }
}
alert(randNum([7, 10, 11],7));
```

But somtimes it returns the numbers I want it to return and sometimes it returns undefined.
What is the problem?

Comment: Just add return keyworkd before randNum(arr,excludeNum);
`return randNum(arr,excludeNum);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your function doesn't return anything when the generated random number is the one you want to exclude. Add a `return` to the `randNum` function call in the if clause.

```
function randNum(arr,excludeNum){
    var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
    if(arr[randNumber]==excludeNum){
        return randNum(arr,excludeNum);
    }else{
        return randNumber;
    }
}
alert(randNum([7, 10, 11],7));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` keyword in front of `randNum(arr,excludeNum);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version that looks up the indexes, removes the unwanted one, and picks random from the others. I use it to shuffle a playlist.

```
function randomIndex(arr, excludeIndex){
    let indexes = Object.keys(arr); //get a list of indexes
    indexes.splice(excludeIndex, 1); //remove the unwanted
    return indexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * indexes.length)]; //pick a new index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using floor and eventually the stack will fill up. (also I think that you missed return)

Why not just remove that number from the array and chose a random index into the rest of it?